# TP-Link JetStream switch - Giving Out IP's to random devices

Tags: tp-link

We have a fairly large, network with several switches, and a router.
Suddenly we observed two PC's getting IP addresses in a range we don't use.

The network uses the 10.0.0.0/16 range, and one device always got 192.168.0.114, with no internet access. The gateway address on that pc was 192.168.0.1.
We could ping that gateway, and even login, it turned out it is the TP-Link T2600G-52TS switch, which had an uptime of ~500 days. Checking the configs, we saw that there are L3 / VLAN functions, and DHCP clients - even though the DHCP server is NOT enabled. ...

Trying to switch off L3 functions had only the result of the web interface beeing inaccessible. A physical restart restored login though.

We want to use the switch as a pure switch, without L3 functions like VLANs and without a DHCP server, .. but have access to the switch admin interface. The manual is a bit confusing on this subject, it says we can set the VLAN interface to a different IP and range ...

Trying to update the firmware now. Any suggestions how to set the switch as a pure switch?

Comment: I'd contact TP-Link to be honest, sounds like a firmware bug to me

Comment: https://static.tp-link.com/2020/202011/20201103/1910012903_T16_T26_UG.pdf

Comment: https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/t2600g-52ts/

Comment: The firmware update did not resolve the issue. :/